# Create a Tree of Object Recursively (Python)

Tags: python, graph, breadth-first-search

i would like to create a tree of objects called State.

Each State has a list of 4 robots and each states have differents robots coordinates.
The goal is to create a graph which will be solved by a Breadth First Search Algorithm.
(The original game is RicochetRobot maybe you guys know it).

```
class State: 
  
    
    def __init__(self,parent,childs,robots,cpt,):
        self.parent = parent
        self.childs = childs
        self.robots = robots
        self.cpt = cpt
```

I created a function create_child to do this

```
 def create_child(self,depth):
        #UP
        #Depth is the tree height
        if depth==0:
            print("STOP")
            return
        else : 
      
            for i in range(4):
            
                #Copying the robots of the current object 
                temp = copy.deepcopy(self.robots)
            
            
                
                
                #Getting robot to move index
                temp_robot = temp[i]
            
                #removing this robot from the list
                temp.pop(i)
        
                
                #Moving up the robot and inserting it in the list
                #Moving up is a simple function which increment the y of the robot
                temp.insert(i,moving_up(temp_robot,create_board(init_robot())))
            
                
                
                #Adding a new child into childs list
                self.childs.append(State(self,self.childs,temp,self.cpt+1))
            
            #Decrementing the depth
            depth-=1
            #Recursivity
            for child in self.childs:
                child.create_child(depth)
```

My problem is that when depth = 0 , it print STOP,but it doesnt return None, and the function keep going.
Anynone knows from where it come froms?
Also, if you can give advice on how to make my tree in an easier way it would be nice.

Comment: It *does* return `None`. That doesn't prevent the *prior* recursive call from continuing. Imagine if you had multiple copies of the function like `create_child0`, `create_child1` etc., each of which is the same except for the names, and except that you always call `create_child0` when the `depth` that you pass will be exactly 0, call `create_child1` instead when the depth will be exactly 1, etc. If you had that code, would you see what is wrong with your approach? The recursion works *the same way*.

Comment: Yes i think i see , with the explanation you gave me , does it mean that in my code, i always go deep but i never go back up? Like if i use your example does it mean that , when depth is 3 for example, it will call create_child3 but it will never go back to create_child2 to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i think i found a solution , here it is :

```
depth = 1
parent = Initial_State
for j in range(depth):
   
    for i in range(len(parent.childs)-1):
        parent.childs[i].create_child()
    parent = parent.childs[i]
```

It seems to be working. I dont use recursion anymore, i do it in a more iterative way and outside the function and it seems good.

Thank you